Tracking Down - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by Error
I'm trying to fix this error
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ~ wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/class-wpcode-snippet-execute.php(292) : eval()'d code:4)
which is crashing some posts and also listing places it's showing up (with the header footer being called again).
I'm not sure why it's calling up the header footer thing as I'm using WP Code Snippets to add custom taxonomies.
Line 292 reads
eval( $code ); // phpcs:ignore Squiz.PHP.Eval.Discouraged

inside of
    try {
        eval( $code ); // phpcs:ignore Squiz.PHP.Eval.Discouraged
    } catch ( Error $e ) {
        $error = array(
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'line'    => $e->getLine(),
        );
    }

I don't recall adding in any changes and ran into this error as I went to build out a section with posts.
I'm using WPCode to setup custom post types and have had this as my code
// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype_06() {

register_post_type( ' modality_post', $args);
// CPT Options
    array(
        $supports = array(
            'title', // post title
            'editor', // post content
            'author', // post author
            'thumbnail', // featured images
            'excerpt', // post excerpt
            'custom-fields', // custom fields
            'comments', // post comments
            'revisions', // post revisions
            'post-formats', // post formats
            'categories', // post categories
            'tags', // post tags
        ),
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Modality Post', 'plural'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Modality Post', 'singular'),
            'menu_name' => _x('Modality Post', 'admin menu'),
            'name_admin_bar' => _x('Modality Post', 'admin bar'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New  modality_post'),
            'new_item' => __('New  modality_post'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit  modality_post'),
            'view_item' => __('View  modality_post'),
            'all_items' => __('All  modality_post'),
            'search_items' => __('Search  modality_post'),
            'not_found' => __('No  modality_post found.'),
        ),
        $args = array(
            'supports' => $supports,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => ' modality_post'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'taxonomies'  => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        )
    
);
register_post_type(' modality_post', $args);
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_06' );


Who put in eval()? I agree with your codesniffer, it is discouraged. What does $code contain?

Whatever is in $code is what's causing the error

added in the WP Code that's likely $code
